# KeyError at /registration/ value 'password1'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I create a new model with additional fields for the `User`.

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        birthday = models.DateField(u'Birthday', blank=True, null=True)
        avatar = models.ImageField(Avatar', upload_to='profile/avatar', blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.user
```

Then I create registration form for users:

```
class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
        username = forms.CharField(label=(u'Enter Your Username'))
        email = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Enter Your E-mail'))
        password = forms.CharField(label=(u'Enter Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
        password1 = forms.CharField(label=(u'Verify Your Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

        class Meta:
                model = UserProfile
                exclude = ('user',)

        def clean_email(self):
                email = self.cleaned_data['email']
                try:
                        User.objects.get(email=email)
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                        return email
                raise forms.ValidationError("User with same e-mail is already exist, please type another email")

        def clean_password(self):
                password = self.cleaned_data['password']
                password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']

                if not password1:
                        raise forms.ValidationError("You have ti verify your password")
                if password != password1:
                        raise forms.ValidationError("Your passwords doesn't match")
                return password1
```

And this is my view for registration page:

```
def UserProfileRegistration(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/info/')
        if request.method == 'POST':
                form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                        user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
                        user.save()
                        user_profile = UserProfile(user=user)
                        user_profile.save()
                        return HttpResponseRedirect('/info/')
                else:
                        return render(request, 'profiles/registration.html', {'form':form})
        else:
                form = RegistrationForm()
                context = {'form':form}
                return render (request, 'profiles/registration.html', context)
```

It doesn't matter if i fill passwords fields right or wrong but i have the same error `KeyError at /registration/`, `Exception Value: 'password1'`. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`password1` is not guaranteed to have been added to `cleaned_data` by the time `clean_password()` is called. For any validation that requires the presence of more than one field, you should do it in the general `clean()` method.

Answer (score 1):

For model forms if you specify a non model field like password1 you have to mention the fields attribute in the form meta class.

A model form will only include the existing model fields. Add this in the model form meta class:

```
class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'password1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Django User already has email no need to add(see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#user-objects)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        birthday = models.DateField(u'Birthday', blank=True, null=True)
        avatar = models.ImageField(Avatar', upload_to='profile/avatar', blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.user
```

Besides, you also need to add clean() for password1 as password in forms.